# Der Unterschied zwischen „sich mit etwas zu schaffen machen“ und „sich mit etwas beschäftigen“

Tags: grammar, word-usage, difference, word-choice

> Ich mache mich mit Deutschlernen zu schaffen.
>
> Ich beschäftige mich mit Deutschlernen.

In meinem Wörterbuch steht, dass beides »to busy oneself with something« bedeutet. Ich weiß, wann man das zweite Verb benutzt, aber ich weiß nicht, wann man das erste verwendet und in welchem Kontext es verwendet wird. Handelt es sich hierbei um „Beamtendeutsch“?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sich mit etwas beschäftigen* ist eher generell.
Man sagt es, wenn man an/mit einer Sache arbeitet/zu tun hat.

Im Englischen würde man es wohl mit *to work on something* übersetzen.

*Sich an etwas zu schaffen machen* bedeutet eher, dass man sich an die Arbeit macht, bzw. mit der Arbeit beginnt.

Ich würde es eher mit *to start/begin working on something* übersetzen.

Übrigens:

> Ich mache mich mit Deutschlernen zu schaffen.

ergibt keinen Sinn bzw. keiner würde es sagen.

Comment: Servus und willkommen auf dem Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [tour] der Seite nehmen. Wenn du mehr darüber erfahren möchtest, wie sie funktioniert, besuche das [help].

Comment: @Jan, vielen Dank!

Comment: *to start/begin working on something* klingt aber an sich neutral, während bei *sich an etwas zu schaffen machen* normalerweise eine verbrecherische Absicht mitschwingt.

Answer (score 4):

Wie schon in anderen Antworten genannt, ist *sich mit etwas beschäftigen* recht allgemein.

Ich möchte hiermit hervorheben, dass *sich **mit** etwas zu schaffen machen* meines Wissens absolut ungebräuchlich ist; nur die Formulierung *sich **an** etwas zu schaffen machen* wird verwendet.

Letzere Formulierung ist dabei auch normalerweise nicht "neutral", sondern es schwingt eine Andeutung verbrecherischen Verhaltens mit:

- *sich an einer Tür zu schaffen machen* bedeutet eher nicht, dass jemand einfach an einer Tür arbeitet, sondern dass er dabei ist, sie (als Einbrecher) aufzubrechen.
- *sich an einem Motor zu schaffen machen* würde ich als Beschreibung eines Sabotageakts verstehen.

etc.

Dieser Eindruck wird bestätigt durch eine kurze Google-Suche nach

> "macht sich an" "zu schaffen"

Die erste Ergebnisseite listet z.B. momentan folgende Seiten auf:

- ["Polizei: Unbekannter macht sich an Opels zu schaffen"](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi36be4rMTJAhXI7w4KHRUzBmQQFggjMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.swp.de%2Fheidenheim%2Flokales%2Fpolizeibericht%2FUnbekannter-macht-sich-an-Opels-zu-schaffen%3Bart1180840%2C3505144&usg=AFQjCNFffGxbrDy1l_3kX2SEWyMo79-DXQ&bvm=bv.108538919,d.ZWU)
- ["Unbekannter macht sich an Siloballen zu schaffen"](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi36be4rMTJAhXI7w4KHRUzBmQQFggqMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wochenblatt.de%2Fnachrichten%2Fschwandorf%2Fregionales%2FUnbekannter-macht-sich-an-Siloballen-zu-schaffen%3Bart1170%2C331018&usg=AFQjCNFQ7mDU1z5WF1iF0SESmkwJIAi7Pg&bvm=bv.108538919,d.ZWU)
- ["42-Jähriger macht sich an 20 Autos zu schaffen - Stadt Kurier"](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi36be4rMTJAhXI7w4KHRUzBmQQFggwMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stadt-kurier.de%2Fneuss%2F42-jaehriger-macht-sich-an-20-autos-zu-schaffen-aid-1.5566060&usg=AFQjCNGL0-MeI8l_7HpOvYNZBjxtSeXFPw&bvm=bv.108538919,d.ZWU)
- ["Unbekannter macht sich an Auto zu schaffen"](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi36be4rMTJAhXI7w4KHRUzBmQQFggzMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblaulichtreport-saarland.de%2F2015%2F09%2Funbekannter-macht-sich-an-auto-zu-schaffen-2%2F&usg=AFQjCNEmAMohGjjDd_aW0W-hly-EMO5IfA&bvm=bv.108538919,d.ZWU)
- ["Serien-Dieb macht sich an Kirche zu schaffen | Primavera24"](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi36be4rMTJAhXI7w4KHRUzBmQQFgg4MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fprimavera24.de%2Fserien-dieb-macht-sich-an-kirche-zu-schaffen%2F&usg=AFQjCNGEBS3C30oUDtkp5Qm7iUelojpKAA&bvm=bv.108538919,d.ZWU)
- ["Betrunkener macht sich an Gullideckeln zu schaffen"](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi36be4rMTJAhXI7w4KHRUzBmQQFgg9MAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fprimavera24.de%2Fbetrunkener-macht-sich-an-gullideckeln-zu-schaffen%2F&usg=AFQjCNH7WbBXuJGP3NyUL9KihKolefJ5ow&bvm=bv.108538919,d.ZWU)
- ["Unbekannter macht sich an Tür zu schaffen"](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi36be4rMTJAhXI7w4KHRUzBmQQFghCMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.main-echo.de%2Fregional%2Fkreis-main-tauber%2Fart4004%2C499810&usg=AFQjCNE4peknPw1wNQsyScZKQBkTN4C7rQ&bvm=bv.108538919,d.ZWU)
- ["Biberach: Einbrecher macht sich an Tür zu schaffen"](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi36be4rMTJAhXI7w4KHRUzBmQQFghHMAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schwaebische.de%2Fregion_artikel%2C-Einbrecher-macht-sich-an-Tuer-zu-schaffen-_arid%2C5515865_toid%2C112.html&usg=AFQjCNEhDwany0HBKT_-Vex4TgKBDCZxXA)
- ["Einbruch durch den Garten : Nachbarn schöpfen Verdacht"](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi36be4rMTJAhXI7w4KHRUzBmQQFghMMAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wn.de%2FMuenster%2F2193283-Einbruch-durch-den-Garten-Nachbarn-schoepfen-Verdacht&usg=AFQjCNFzjFlxdpH-s0d-n7o_O-ow6LuxbA) (Fundstelle im Text "Ein Einbrecher macht sich an einem Fenster zu schaffen.")
- ["Ulm - Einbrecher macht sich an einem Auto zu schaffen"](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi36be4rMTJAhXI7w4KHRUzBmQQFghTMAk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.t-online.de%2Fregionales%2Fid_76184334%2Fulm-einbrecher-macht-sich-an-einem-auto-zu-schaffen-ein-unbekannter-hatte-es-zwischen-mittwoch-u.html&usg=AFQjCNFt-U-T1Q0n4tlSImpvxstgqdyroA)

Es geht bei all diesen Artikeln ausschließlich um Kriminalität, und auf den folgenden Ergebnisseiten sieht es auch nicht anders aus.

Answer (score 1):

Viel eher als »Beamtendeutsch« würde ich *sich an etwas zu schaffen machen* als umgangssprachlich klassifizieren.

Das Wort *schaffen,* wie auch seine Ableitung *erschaffen,* bedeutet, dass man mit seinen Händen etwas herstellt. Vergleiche mit dem schwäbischen Nationalmotto:

> Schaffe, schaffe, Häusle baue.
>
> (Schaffen, schaffen, Haus bauen.)

Der schwäbische Ethos wird beschrieben als arbeiten, um sich später ein Haus leisten zu können. Theoretisch könnte man sich dabei einen Schreibtischbeamten zwar vorstellen, aber viel eher würde man an einen Ingenieur (konstruieren), oder Handwerker (mit den Händen arbeiten) denken. Deswegen kann man sich gut an *konkreten* Gegenständen zu schaffen machen, aber nicht mit abstrakten oder mit Konzepten.

Für alle folgenden Beispiele könnte man *beschäftigen* verwenden; ob man auch sich daran *zu schaffen machen* kann, steht dahinter:

- Motor reparieren: Definitiv!
- Gartenarbeit: Definitiv!
- Technische Zeichnung/künstlerische Gestaltung: Ja.
- Berichte schreiben: Gerade noch so.
- Korrekturlesen: Eher nicht.
- Verwaltungsaufgaben: Ganz vielleicht aber wahrscheinlich nicht.
- Prüflinge überwachen: Nein.
- Sprachen lernen: Nein. (Es sei denn, du meinst direkt und konkret dich *jetzt* hinzusetzen und Vokabeln zu pauken.)

Zwei konkrete Beispiele, um den Unterschied herauszuarbeiten:

- > Ich beschäftige mich mit meiner Idee.

  Wahrscheinlich geht es noch um Denken und Ausformulieren der Idee an sich, am Schreibtisch, im Liegestuhl oder auch am Zeichenbrett.
- > Ich mache mich an meiner Idee zu schaffen.

  Die Idee betrifft etwas, dass ich konstruktiv herstellen kann, und ich mache mich jetzt an die Umsetzung.

Comment: Ich würde *sich an etwas zu schaffen machen* in keinem der von dir genannten Fälle benutzen, außer, ich führe Übles im Schilde. *sich an einer technischen Zeichnung zu schaffen machen* würde für mich implizieren, sie entweder zu entwenden oder ein paar Zahlen abzuändern, um beispielsweise aus einem stabilen Gebäude ein einsturzgefährdetes zu machen. Der Eindruck wird auch von [Beispielen, die ich in meiner Antwort aufgeführt habe](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/26954/5999), bestätigt.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Danke für den Hinweis auf die falsche Präposition. Ich kann deine Antwort durchaus nachvollziehen, meine aber, dass der Kontext dort die Musik macht. Der Ausdruck selbst trägt den kriminellen Unterton meines Erachtens nicht. Vielleicht vertrete ich aber auch eine Minderheiten- oder Einzelmeinung ;)